# EF 6 Code First Class Generation Named and Mapped Incorrectly

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an existing database with a table to which I have added 2 new columns.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks](
    [TaskId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResolutionId] [int] NULL,
    [AmendedCategoryId] [int] NULL, -- New column
    [AmendedResolutionId] [int] NULL, -- New column
)
```

These columns (each is an int) have a foreign key relationship which is the same as the 2 previously existing columns ("CategoryId" and "AmendedCategoryId" each FK to [TaskCategory] and "ResolutionId" and "AmendedResolutionId" each FK to [TaskResolution]).

When I use EF6 Code First to generate the C# data access classes for this, the results are confusing (to say the least).

Here is an example of what EF is producing:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<TaskCategory>()
        .HasMany(e => e.TaskCategory1)
        .WithOptional(e => e.TaskCategory2)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentCategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TaskCategory>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Tasks)
        .WithOptional(e => e.TaskCategory)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.AmendedCategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TaskCategory>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Tasks1)
        .WithRequired(e => e.TaskCategory1)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.CategoryId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Resulting in the following:

1. The class property names for the new "Amended" columns (ex: "AmendedTaskCategory", "AmendedTaskResolution") do not match the
   column names from the table, although the "AmendedTaskCategoryId"
   and "AmendedTaskResolutionId" names DO match. Instead they have
   "TaskCategory1" and "TaskResolution1" for their names.
2. The "modelBuilder.Entity" code that was generated is mapping the
   "original" column to the new equivalent (ex: "TaskCategory" is being
   mapped to "AmendedTaskCategory"), and the original generated
   property is being left null (which is causing problems down-stream).
3. Why is EF generating the "1" and "2" classes &
   properties?

How can I get Entity Framework 6 to "correctly" name and map the generated the classes and properties in the classes resulting from using the "Code First" EF functionality?

Comment: Since you are using Code First can we see the code please

Comment: I am using the "Code First from database" to generate the DAL classes, so I don't have any existing code to show (that I am aware of?). (I am new to EF, so if I am being dumb / ignorant, please forgive me.)

Comment: please show the generated data access classes for the relevant tables